# Find the number of distinct values in a column of table using database schema metadata

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql, table-statistics

I'm looking for a SQL Server query to find the number of distinct values in a column of a table (cardinality of columns) using database schema metadata. I have only database metadata and cannot query the table.

I have this query but it directly query the table. I want to get the same information by querying database schema metadata.

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(MAX) = 'tablename';
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT 
    @SQL += 'SELECT ''' + COLUMN_NAME + ''' AS ColumnName, 
                    COUNT(DISTINCT [' + COLUMN_NAME + ']) AS Cardinality 
             FROM [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + @TableName + '] 
             UNION ALL '
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME = @TableName;

SET @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 10) 
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: The metadata you're referencing in your post is schema-level metadata. It cannot tell you any information about the values in those columns.

Comment: You can't get information about the data in a table without querying the table. Metadata of the schema is not metadata of the data.

Comment: You can perhaps query the statistics dmvs, although not sure if the histograms are available without parsing show statistics. Why can't you just query the tables normally.

Comment: @siggemannen [sys.dm_db_stats_histogram](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-stats-histogram-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: @Nithya When you say you "cannot query the table." is this because you don't have `SELECT` permissions on it?

Comment: If there was an index on the column in question, you could use index cardinality statistics for an estimate

Comment: @MartinSmith "cannot query the table." - I mean, I am trying to run on a large volume live database and I don't want to hamper the database performance because of this statistical queries.

Comment: @Bohemian - yeah thats perfect. Its good enough if i get indexed column cardinalities for table. Could you suggest.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the statistics histogram, if it exists, for the column. You would need a single-column statistics object with just that column as the key.

```sql
SELECT
  ColumnName = c.name,
  StatsName = s.name,
  h.distinct_range_rows
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
JOIN sys.stats s
  ON s.object_id = t.object_id
 AND c.column_id = (
    SELECT MIN(sc.column_id)
    FROM sys.stats_columns sc
    WHERE sc.object_id = t.object_id
      AND sc.stats_id = s.stats_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1  -- single-column stats only
  )
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      distinct_range_rows = SUM(h.distinct_range_rows)
    FROM sys.dm_db_stats_histogram(t.object_id, s.stats_id) h
) h
WHERE t.name = @TableName;
```

You need the right permissions for this to work. The docs say

> Requires that the user has select permissions on statistics columns or the user owns the table or the user is a member of the sysadmin fixed server role, the db_owner fixed database role, or the db_ddladmin fixed database role.

Note that table statistics are not perfectly reliable, especially if a full scan has not been done recently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got something closer to the expected values. have access to sys.dm_db_stats_histogram. Am able to execute the above query after a full scan, but looks like the results are inaccurate. It would be good if i get accurate cardinality results for indexed columns (which is distinct column values count for the indexed columns.) Could you suggest

Comment: For accurate results - you need to run against the real tables, otherwise you can get fast and inaccurate only

Comment: @NithyaM So you did `UPDATE STATISTICS YourTable WITH FULLSCAN`? Note that it doesn't really help performance, as it's going to obviously scan the whole table to get the statistics, and if you want accurate results you could equally scan the table yourself.